# Django Channels AsyncWebSocketConsumer ConnectionClosedError 1005

Tags: django, django-channels, asgi, django-redis

I am writing a django channels application and noticed an exception when handling a heartbeat function related to websocket status code which I haven't been able to find any existing issues for. This is in an AsyncWebsocketConsumer backed by redis.

`ConnectionClosedError: websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedError: received 1005 (no status code [internal]); then sent 1005 (no status code [internal])`

```py
    async def receive(self, text_data):
        try:
            if text_data == "healthcheck":
                await self.send(
                    text_data=json.dumps({"type": "healthcheck", "data": self.group_name})
                )
            else:
                logger.info(f"Unsupported WS Event: {text_data}")
                pass
        except:
            logger.exception("Failed to handle message from client")
```

Also receive this error

`RuntimeError: RuntimeError: Unexpected ASGI message 'websocket.send', after sending 'websocket.close'.`

My `disconnect` implementation is

```py
   async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        try:
            # Leave room group
            await self.channel_layer.group_discard(self.group_name, self.channel_name)

            await self.log_request("disconnect")
        except:
            logger.exception("Failed to disconnect user from socket")
```

Comment: Can you share a repro project on GitHub?

Comment: Read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).